# How to rotate a SpriteView?

Tags: ios, swiftui, spriteview

> UPDATE: The `SpriteView` rotation will work in a simulator, but not on a real device (in my case an iPhone 11 with iOS 14b3). See @Asperi comment. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

`SpriteView`: [A SwiftUI view that renders a SpriteKit scene.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/spriteview)
Ok.

First, the happy path. The `Rectangle` below will rotate just fine:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            // Rectangle test (rotates just fine)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

As expected:

[image: rotationRectangle]

Great.
Now when I try to do the same with a `SpriteView`:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            SpriteView(scene: createSKScene(with: geometry.size))
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height / 2)
        }
    }

    func createSKScene(with size: CGSize) -> SKScene {
        let scene = SKScene()
        scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        return scene
    }
}
```

The view will not rotate.

[image: spriteView]

So clearly I'm missing something. Do you know what I'm missing?

---

Now one thing that is very curious...
By just adding this line: `let scene = SKScene()`

... views will simply stop rotating.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    // By adding this line, views won't rotate anymore. ???
    let scene = SKScene()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in

            // Now the rectangle will NOT rotate anymore.
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.red)
                .frame(width: geometry.size.width / 2, height: geometry.size.height / 2)
        }
    }
}
```

This is driving me nuts!

**Xcode**: 12.0 beta 3
**iOS**: 14 beta 3

Comment: Works similarly fine on Xcode 12b3 / iOS 14 Simulator. Did you use device?

Comment: Really? Damn... Yes, I'm using a physical device, iPhone 11, iOS 14b3. Indeed, I just confirmed. It works on the simulator but not on the physical device. Oh, fuck me... I think I'm updating my question with this info... and also creating a bug. :/ Thanks for checking it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed in Xcode 12 beta 6.

```swift
¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```